# A function in O(n^2) but not in Ω(n^2) also in Ω(n) but not in O(n)

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I am working on asymptotic relations in my book for an interview but I do not understand one question.

Give an example of a function that is in O(n^2) but not in Ω(n^2) also in Ω(n) but not in O(n).

Is there a quick way that I can find a suitable function?

Tried many examples but still can't find the perfect function that suits the criteria

Here is the way that I tried

cn < f(n) < cn^2

Comment: There are infinitely many. Make sure you understand the definitions of big-O and big-Ω.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part:

> Give an example of a function that is in O(n^2) but not in Ω(n^2)

you can say for example `f(n) = n`

and for the second part:

> Give an example of a function that is in Ω(n) but not in O(n)

you can say `g(n) = n^2`

and many more examples you can come up with.

If you want both conditions to be held at the same time:

> Give an example of a function that is in O(n^2) but not in Ω(n^2) also in Ω(n) but not in O(n).

you can say: `h(n) = n^(1.5)`